# Issue styling a header in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have [this](http://jsbin.com/bireqabujo/2/edit?html,css,output) header written in CSS and HTML, I'm trying to make it in react native, but seems like `position: 'absolute'` removes my icon from the scene.

So, In my react-native app I have the following markup:

```
<View
   style={header}>

      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
         onPress={this.props.callback}>

      <View>
        <Image
          style={headerIcon}
          source={require('./img/back.png')} />
      </View>
   </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

   <Text style={headerTitle}>{this.props.title.toUpperCase()}</Text>
</View>
```

And the following stylesheet

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        height: 55,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: colors.white,
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },

    headerTitle: {
        color: colors.black,
        fontFamily: 'Dosis',
        fontSize: 15
    },

    headerIcon: {
        width: 22,
        height: 16
    }
})
```

Can someone explain me how to make the style for the react-native header to look like http://jsbin.com/bireqabujo/2/edit?html,css,output ?

Comment: What's it doing without setting `position:absolute`? maybe a screenshot? thanks!

Comment: hey @BradBumbalough, so if i set position:absolute, the icon will not show up anymore, like visibility:hidden

Comment: Shouldn´t it be <View style={styles.header }>?

Comment: @BigPun86 i'm using es6 destructuring object like const { header }  = style, which is equal with const header = style.header

Comment: Oh sorry my bad :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<View style={styles.header}>

    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={this.props.callback}>
        <View>
            <Image
                style={styles.headerIcon}
                source={require('./img/back.png')} />
        </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

    <View style={styles.headerTitleWrapper}><Text style={styles.headerTitle}>MY TITLE</Text></View>
</View>
```

And change your style to this

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    header: {
        height: 55,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },

    headerTitleWrapper: {flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center', 
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    headerTitle: {
        color: 'black',
        fontFamily: 'Dosis',
        fontSize: 15
    },

    headerIcon: {
        width: 22,
        height: 16
    }
})
```

**Check This on**

https://rnplay.org/apps/iSpc1Q

Comment: Hey @Faheem, thanks for your answer but if you see the following screenshot you can see that the text its not in the middle, thats why i wanted position:absolute - http://prntscr.com/bepdyr

Comment: however, if not any other solution I can add paddingLeft: MARGIN OF THE ICON and paddingRight: MARGIN OF THE ICON + icon width